# Spring Boot with MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I am new to Spring Boot and MongoDb. 
Trying some examples with Mongo Repositories and Spring Boot. 
But after going through some of the documents found that Mongo Template is will be a better option. Unable to get a proper Spring Boot with Mongo Template example.

1. Can someone please help me out with an example for the same.
2. Do we need to create a User defined Repositories interface and extend Repositories or CRUD Repository, while trying for Mongo Template ?

Comment: did you find any solution to this? can we use both template and repositories together in same project ? lets say if I want to implement a custom repository  can I use template to do so ?

Answer (score 7):

For further explanation, you can even use both at the same time.

`MongoRepository` is just an abstraction layer, like `MongoTemplate`, but with simpler interface.

If you found doing some kind of operation is too complicated with Spring [query-creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), and somehow doesn't want to use [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) (for example, you want IDE type hint when constructing queries), you can extend the `MongoRepository` and use `MongoTemplate` as the query mechanism.

First we extend our repository with our custom interface.

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends MongoRepository<Article, String>, CustomArticleRepository {
}
```

Then declare the interface.

```
public interface CustomArticleRepository {
    List<Article> getArticleFilteredByPage(int page, int num);
}
```

And then implement our custom repository. We can autowire the `MongoTemplate` here and use it to query the database.

```
public class CustomArticleRepositoryImpl implements CustomArticleRepository {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Article> getArticleFilteredByPage(int page, int num) {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Article.class)
                .skip(page * num)
                .take(num);
    }
}
```

Last, we use the `ArticleRepository`.

```
@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    public List<Article> getArticleByPage() {
        return articleRepository.getArticleFilteredByPage(1, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe using both mongo template and mongo repository together creates two database connections

Answer (score 4):

I have found some examples using Mongo Template

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/

If you are interested in using JPA, please see below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>{mongo.driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
#Mongo DB
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.port=
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=
spring.data.mongodb.uri=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
```

SpringBoot class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class UserApp {
```

Mongo Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Comment: Hi Sarvanna, My question is do we need to create a Repository class when we are working with Mongo Template? As far as I read Mongo Template and Mongo Repository are two different entities.

Comment: You don't need to create both, template will be basically a wrapper over connection factory provide basic CRUD operations

Comment: The links I have posted is for using template but if you want to use JPA you can see the code I posted