# Spring Boot with MongoTemplate and services - unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm refactoring a codebase in order to have a single point of access to the repository
I was following the guideline of [Spring Boot with MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288258/spring-boot-with-mongotemplate)

however I'm not able to build the project anymore, I'm thinking the problem being some wrong annotations or most probably an inheritance trouble

The Repository

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends MongoRepositoryExtended<CustomType, String>,RepositoryTemplate {
(...
lots of custom queries
...)
}
```

The RepositoryTemplate(same package of repository):

```
public interface RepositoryTemplate {

    List<String> distinctField(String fieldName);
}
```

the RepositoryTemplateImpl(same package of ServiceImpl):

```
public class RepositoryTemplateImpl implements RepositoryTemplate {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;


    @Override
    public List<String> distinctField(String fieldName) {
        List<String> fieldNames = template.findDistinct(fieldName, CustomType.class, String.class);
        return fieldNames;
    }
}
```

The ServiceImpl (which needs to implement the service first obv):

```
 @Service
 public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

 private Repository repository;
 @Autowired
 ServiceImpl(Repository repository){
this.repository=repository;
}

(...)

@Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<SpecialType>> specialMethod(String fieldNames) {

        List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params = Arrays.asList(fieldNames.split("/"));

        List<SpecialType> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String field : params) {
            (..some method..)
            }

            if (!found) {
                continue;
            }

            result.setField(field);
            **result.setValues(repository.distinctField(field));**

            list.add(result);
        }
```

No matter different changes I keep getting the same Unsatisfied Dependency Error

```
rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\..]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Repository' defined in com.organization.microservice.repository.Repository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property distinctField found for type CustomType!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.com.organization.microservice.ManagerApplication.main(ManagerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

there is nothing in the CustomTypes similar to Field in naming

I tried changing the name of the custom query distinctField to getDistinctField , FindDistinctField ecc. but at this point I think I might have to look at some other direction. Any Suggestion or tip?

Comment: Please post CustomType and also post query in repository

Comment: please post the controller code

Comment: i specified that CustomType has nothing similar to field